# CSS how to make special div shape

Tags: css, css-shapes

Any idea how to make the div shape like this ?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a rectangle and skew the Y axis using the [CSS3 `transform` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform).

In this case, `transform: skewY(-20deg)` will work.

```css
.shape {
    border: 2px solid;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100px;
    transform: skewY(-20deg);
    margin: 2em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

This will work in all modern browsers and will fall back to a rectangle in older browsers.

```css
.skewed {
  border: solid 5px black;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  transform: skewY(-30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="skewed"></div>
```

Comment: As an interesting aside, http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ has some pretty interesting shapes created with CSS.